# Why this ReactJs App re-renders entirely on state update but without using the state anywhere?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having a weird issue. I have this code. After adding setEmail(value) the Login.js component keeps re-rendering when I start to type in the textBox while I'm not even using the `email` variable nowhere. I checked the parent element of the `Login.js` but it doesn't have that issue.

Appreciate your help.

PS: I cannot type anything in the text boxes after typing the first character. It keeps re-rendering without stopping

**Login.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

import styles from "../styles/screens/screen.module.scss";
import customStyles from "../styles/screens/login.module.scss";

import Card from "../components/Card";
import GoogleButton from "../components/GoogleButton";
import Loading from "../components/Loading";
import TextInput from "../components/TextInput";
import Button from "../components/Button";

import welcomeImage from "../assets/images/welcomeImage.svg";
import emailIcon from "../assets/images/emailIcon.svg";
import lockIcon from "../assets/images/lockIcon.svg";

export default function Login() {
  const loading = false;
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleLogin = async () => {};

  const handleCreateAccount = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigate("/sign-up");
  };

  const handleEmailUpdate = (value) => {
    setEmail(value); //with this it keeps re-rendering
    //console.log(value); //this works fine
  };

  const handlePasswordUpdate = (value) => {};

  const CardContent = () => {
    return (
      <div className={styles.cardContent}>
       
        <div className={`${styles.inputForm} ${customStyles.inputForm}`}>
          <TextInput
            label="Email"
            type="email"
            icon={emailIcon}
            placeholder={"email@gmail.com"}
            style={{ borderRadius: "10px 10px 0 0 " }}
            onChange={handleEmailUpdate}
          />
          <TextInput
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            icon={lockIcon}
            placeholder={"*********"}
            style={{ borderRadius: "0 0 10px 10px" }}
            onChange={handlePasswordUpdate}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Card
        title="Sign In"
        subtitle="Sign in to continue"
        content={<CardContent />}
        leftImage={welcomeImage}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**TextInput.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styles from "../styles/components/textInput.module.scss";

import validIcon from "../assets/images/validIcon.svg";

export default function TextInput({
  label,
  type,
  icon,
  style,
  onChange,
  value,
  placeholder,
  disabled,
  validation,
  showValidIcon,
}) {
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
    if (validation) {
      setValid(validation.test(e.target.value));
    }
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(e.target.value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={`${styles.inputWrapper} ${
        focused ? styles.focusedWrapper : ""
      }`}
      style={style}
    >
      {icon && (
        <div className={styles.iconContainer}>
          <img src={icon} alt="icon" />
        </div>
      )}
      <div className={styles.inputContainer}>
        <span className={styles.inputLabel}>{label}</span>
        <input
          type={type}
          className={styles.textInput}
          disabled={disabled}
          onChange={handleChange}
          defaultValue={value}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          onFocus={() => setFocused(true)}
          onBlur={() => setFocused(false)}
        />
        {showValidIcon && valid && (
          <img src={validIcon} className={styles.validIcon} />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is how react works - if you setState (regardless of if you actually use that value - though, why would you set it if you don’t need to use it?) react rerenders the component. Are you experiencing a problem?

Comment: @AdamJenkins yes, the textboxes keeps re-rendering entirely. I cannot type anything after typing the first character. If you notice, I’m not using the ‘email’ variable nowhere. Not sure why those keeps re-rendering

Comment: It’s because CardContent is a brand new component created every time your parent is re-rendered. You should never declare a component inside the body of another component. If you change it to `CardContent()` instead of `<CardContent/>`, it’ll work

Comment: @AdamJenkins ah yes! I'm a total idiot. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Every time you use set function, there will always be a re-render. But there is one exception, when the new state value is the same as the current state value, React will assume that the state has not changed and therefore will not trigger a component re-render.

Comment: React documentation has been mentioned it. https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#returns